# Same request mapping for get and post not working for spring

Tags: java, spring

I have written following controller using spring MVC.
Request URL /webbroker/ is mapped to both request GET and POST.For get its working fine but for POST its throwing below error.

> Request method GET not supported.

Any idea why its behaving like this?

```
@Controller
public class ProxyController {

    @Autowired
    private RequestHandler reqHandler;

    @Autowired
    private ResponseHandler responseHandler;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/webbroker/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void edgefxGetRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {        
        HttpURLConnection connection = this.reqHandler.handleRequest(httpRequest, httpResponse, false);
        this.responseHandler.sendResponse(connection, httpResponse);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/webbroker/**", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void edgefxPostRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = this.reqHandler.handleRequest(httpRequest, httpResponse, true);
        this.responseHandler.sendResponse(connection, httpResponse);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/webbroker-strong/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void edgefxStrongGetRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {        
        HttpURLConnection connection = this.reqHandler.handleRequest( httpRequest, httpResponse, false);
        this.responseHandler.sendResponse(connection, httpResponse);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/webbroker-strong/**", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void edgefxStrongPostRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = this.reqHandler.handleRequest(httpRequest, httpResponse, true);
        this.responseHandler.sendResponse(connection, httpResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just post the exception message post the full stacktrace/logging...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webbroker/**", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public void edgefxRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
        throws IOException {        
    HttpURLConnection connection = this.reqHandler.handleRequest(httpRequest, httpResponse, false);
    this.responseHandler.sendResponse(connection, httpResponse);
}
```

you don't need to replicate your *handler method* for both HTTP methods. Just declare the `method` param as an array.

Comment: But how about such cases like actually different processing block for each of two methods? Like I want to do something for POST and do something *different* for GET ? I need two controllers